# Is there any issue with changing the model database to SIMPLE recovery model?

Tags: sql-server, recovery-model

The model database is in FULL recovery model. I know that new dbs follow the model db template and so will be automatically in FULL recovery model.

So that the new dbs are automatically in SIMPLE model, I want to change the recovery model of the model db to SIMPLE. Is there any concern with changing the model database to SIMPLE recovery model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. That's the whole point of `model`, it's a [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database?view=sql-server-ver15) for creating new databases. The only caveat is that it's used in `tempdb` creation on startup, so messing it makes starting SQL Server a bit tricky.

Depending on how database deployment is being done, it might be that changing the recovery settings in `model` are not sufficient to have an effect. If new databases are restored from backups, those retrain their old recovery options. Also, databases deployed via development tools might override settings from `model`.

Answer (score 0):

No, but be aware if the database creation script explicitly specifies FULL RECOVERY this will overrule the template setting of the model database